# Error in changing the background color from white to black

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to change the background color from white to black. So i am trying to go through all the pixels and check whether its white or no if so change the value to 0. But something went wrong.

**Here is my code**

```
Mat img = imread("t.PNG");
for (int x = 0; x < img.rows; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < img.cols; y++)
    {
        if (img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y))[0] >=245 && img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y))[1] >= 245 && img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y))[2] >= 245)
        {

            img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = { 0,0,0 };
        }       
    }   
}
imwrite("img.png",img);
imshow(" ",img);
waitKey(0);
```

**here is the image i am trying to convert**

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in more details what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate pixel by pixel, change the loop for this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < img.rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < img.cols; col++)
    {
        if (img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col, row))[0] >=245 && img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col, row))[1] >= 245 && img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col, row))[2] >= 245)
        {
            img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col, row)) = { 0,0,0 };
        }
    }
}
```

A better and clearly solution is to use a background mask. Change the loop for this:

```
cv::Mat gray,mask;
cv::cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::compare(gray, cv::Scalar(245,245,245), mask, CV_CMP_GT);
img.setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,0), mask);
```

Answer (score 1):

From this code

```
for (int x = 0; x < img.rows; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < img.cols; y++)
    {
```

x - is row number, y is a column number, but from this code:

```
img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y))
```

x is column number, y is a row number.

So, you should shange the variables in the loops.